# AngularJS populate a <select> field based on input from previous <select> field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have 2 dropdown menus that are dependent on one another. The first one works perfectly, but I want the second dropdown to populate based on the choice in the first menu. I realize that similar questions have been asked before, but my data seems to be in a different format. Here is my code:

```
<body ng-app="patientSim" ng-controller="patientCtrl">

<button style="width:20%;" ng-click="addChar()">Add Characteristic</button>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3"><select ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="x.cat as (x.cat | underFilter) for x in (enumChars | duplicateFilter)"></select></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x.enumName as (x.enumName | underFilter) for x in enumChars"></select></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><button ng-click="eqWeight()">Equalize Weights</button></div>
    <div class="col-md-3"><button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button></div>
</div>
```

And here are 2 sections of the JSON:

```
 {
        "enumID": 1,
        "enumName": "Gender",
        "isTree": false,
        "enumAlloc": 10,
        "enumVals": [
            "Unknown",
            "Male",
            "Female",
            "Transgender"
        ],
        "enumText": null,
        "cat": "Demographics"
    }, 
      {
        "enumID": 2,
        "enumName": "Race",
        "isTree": false,
        "enumAlloc": 15,
        "enumVals": [
            "Unknown",
            "American Indian/Alaska Native",
            "Asian",
            "Black",
            "Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander",
            "White/Caucasian",
            "Other"
        ],
        "enumText": null,
        "cat": "Demographics"
    },
```

The first dropdown is populated with "Demographics" and "Diseases and Injuries", both under the "cat" name. The entire file contains 5 "Demographics" sections and 1 "Diseases and Injures" section. All 6 sections are stored in a scope value called enumChars, which I used in ng-options. There are over 45,000 values for some sections, so I didn't want to post them here. My goal is for the second dropdown to populate with the "enumName" corresponding to the "cat". So for example, if I select "Demographics" in the first dropdown, the second dropdown will populate with "Gender", "Race", and the other enumName values in the other sections also containing "cat": "Demographics". How would I go about doing this? Thanks!!

Comment: Please share your angular JS code to debug easily

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question well you want to populate with the `enumVals` the **2nd** `<select>` based on the value selected in the **1st.** `<select>`.

Then, if I'm correct, you can do the following:

```js
(function() {
  "use strict";
  angular.module('app', [])
    .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.enumChars = [  
         {  
            "enumID":1,
            "enumName":"Gender",
            "isTree":false,
            "enumAlloc":10,
            "enumVals":[  
               "Unknown",
               "Male",
               "Female",
               "Transgender"
            ],
            "enumText":null,
            "cat":"Any category"
         },
         {  
            "enumID":2,
            "enumName":"Race",
            "isTree":false,
            "enumAlloc":15,
            "enumVals":[  
               "Unknown",
               "American Indian/Alaska Native",
               "Asian",
               "Black",
               "Native Hawaiian/Other Pacific Islander",
               "White/Caucasian",
               "Other"
            ],
            "enumText":null,
            "cat":"Demographics"
         }
      ];
    });
})();
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-messages/1.5.7/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <button style="width:20%;" ng-click="addChar()">Add Characteristic</button>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <select ng-model="selectedCategory" ng-options="obj as obj.cat for obj in enumChars"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" ng-if="selectedCategory">
      <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="enum for enum in selectedCategory.enumVals"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button ng-click="eqWeight()">Equalize Weights</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```